# Как в jQuery обнулить значение backgroundColor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, анимация

Добрый день. Имею скрипт

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var top = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (top > 0) {
                $(".header").animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                $(".header").animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'none'
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

строка - backgroundColor: 'none' не работает. Какое есть решение?

Comment: Может быть какое то из этих `initial`, `inherit`, `unset` вместо `none`

Comment: К сожалению, ни одно не отменило предыдущее значение фона.

Answer (score 1):

Значение backgoundColor нужно описывать в .css()
Пример:

```
.css({backgroundColor: "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" })
```

Вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (top > 0) {
            $(".header").css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff");
        } else {
            $(".header").css("backgroundColor", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

Более подробное описание представлено [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Добавление к ответу:
`background-color` не может быть изменен через `animate()`, пока не подключен плагин **[jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)**

Также можно подключить библиотеку и попытаться воспроизвести таким образом:

Вариант 2:

```
<!-- include Google's AJAX API loader -->
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<!-- load JQuery and UI from Google (need to use UI to animate colors) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.2");
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (top > 0) {
            $(".header").stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $(".header").stop().animate({backgroundColor: 'none'}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает. Пробовал прописать и

$(".header").css({backgroundColor: '#ffffff'})
$(".header").css({backgroundColor: 'none'})

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский подправил ответ, добавил второй вариант

Comment: Такой вариант работает. Но нет анимации. Важно, чтобы фон появлялся с элементами анимации.

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский минутку, сейчас скорректирую :)

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский Добавил информацию к ответу, для использования в animate() background-color - вам нужно установить плагин, это если вы хотите именно через animate()

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский Добавил альтернативный вариант с подключением библиотеки и animate(). За вами тестирование :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   // Сохраним значение фона
   // each нужен, т.к. у элементов может быть разный фон
   $(".header").each(function(){
     var bg = $(this).css('background-color');
     $(this).data('bg', bg);
   });


        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var top = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (top > 0) {
                $(".header").animate({
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                $(".header").each(function(){
   // Используем значение фона
                    $(this).animate({
                    backgroundColor: $(this).data('bg');
                   }, 1000);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу таким способом

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var top = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (top > 0) {
                $(".header").addClass('fly', 500);
            } else {
                $(".header").removeClass('fly', 500);
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.fly {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: А тк вы анимацию хотели, добавьте в `.fly` - `transition: background-color .5s`

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundColor: 'none'
```

заменить на

```
backgroundColor: 'auto'
```

Comment: Такой вариант пробовал - не работает.